# Trouble Creating Instance of Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have the code below, but I am getting an error when I try to create an instance of the class.

```
class Flight():
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.passengers = []
    
    def add_passenger(self, name):
        if not self.open_seats():
            return False
        self.passengers.append(name)
        return True

    def open_seats(self):
        return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)


f = Flight(3)

people = ["Aicel", "Angela", "Randy", "Monina"]
for person in people:
    success = flight.add_passengers(person)
    if success:
        print(f"Added {person} to flight successfully")
    else:
        print(f"No available seats for {person}")
```

This the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File classflight.py Line 19, in <module>
success = flight.add_passenger(person)
NameError: name 'flight' is not defined
```

Comment: It's *not* defined - double-check what you *did* call your instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you: `name 'flight' is not defined`.

If you look closer at the line in question from the error message (`success = flight.add_passenger(person)`) and the rest of your code, you see that the `Flight` instance that you created is not named `flight` but `f`. So to make your code work,

- *either* change `f = Flight(3)` to `flight = Flight(3)`
- *or* change `success = flight.add_passenger(person)` to `success = f.add_passenger(person)`